# Collecting Letter Scraps, Space ship parts

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am currently trying to collect the letter scraps (to eventually get the achievement for A mystery solved worth 15G points) and the space ship parts (another 15G points for getting that) currently i picked up 20/50 letter scraps and just one space ship part, i am following the IGN gameplay walkthrough to help me with that but i have spend like close to 4 hours getting these and this is what i do currently.

- Check the video.
- mark the location on my map from the video.
- collect.

Has anyone here got these achievements and is there any simpler route for accomplishing these?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By far the easiest way to get all *Letter Scraps* and *Spaceship Parts* is by linking your game to your [*Rockstar SocialClub*](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/) account and use the [interactive *Map Legend*](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/career/checklist) to keep track of the collectibles you've found, and those you haven't yet found.

The map takes a little while to update and your console needs to be online for it to work at its fullest.

Comment: sounds much less painful. let me try that. i think they ought to have given more gamer points for getting these items.

Comment: Just a tip from personal experience: the interactive map is perfect in 99 out of 100 cases. If you aren't finding your item, don't distrust the map - it's accurate. Except for the "tram station site" spaceship part. Technically the map is correct, but it won't help you find the entrance to the subway in the aqueduct which you need to enter to actually make it there.

Comment: @dpatchery True. I remember using a guide for that one, since I couldn't find it on the roof of the skyscrapers and couldn't find a way to the underground. Good thing you mentioned that.

Comment: I would recommend using that map and marking all the collectibles as points of interest on your map.  (Hit Y/Triangle with the map open)

Comment: hey nolonar I just want to thank you for all the help you've given me :). I've upvoted three of your best answers :D.

Answer (score 6):

For finding collectibles and other items: [Here is an interactive map by IGN of Los Santos and Blaine County](http://www.ign.com/maps/gta-5/los-santos-blaine-county)

You can filter the collectibles by UFO parts.  This may be faster than your current approach.